# PHP (7.1) issue with mail , openssl , certificate

Tags: php, openssl, dovecot, exim

In the **php.ini** I have:

```
[openssl]
openssl.cafile= /etc/ssl/cert/mydomaincabundle.crt
```

this line allow email from **PHP** with **SMTP** to be sent from PHP es **Wordpress** or PHP application as i use **mydomain.ext** certificate.

Now that I need [use composer](https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/973) I discovered this line generate SSL error when PHP app like composer try to download data. The error is:

```
file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
```

If i remove the **php.ini** line

```
[openssl]
openssl.cafile= /etc/ssl/cert/mydomaincabundle.crt
```

this issue is solved but i start to see all **PHP mail** fail so applications like **Wordpress** etc are unable to **send email**.

**How I can have mail working and also solve the PHP SSL issue?**

If i remove the **openssl** line with the certificate email sent with **SMTP SSL** will fail.

```
Connection: opening to ssl://domain.it:465, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://domain.it:465 (Unknown error)
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'd normally set `openssl.capath` to the directory containing global and (presumably) local certificates. If you set a single `cafile` instead only that will be used for ***all*** socket connections.

Comment: Hi @mario , I do not know how to solve this issue. If i remove the openssl.cafile mail stop to work but i resolve composer SSL issue, if I keep i will have mail working but composer unable to work with SSL issue.

Comment: You already mentioned that. How about answering the `capth` question or your /etc/ssl/certs` setup? See also [How do you add a certificate authority (CA) to Ubuntu?](//superuser.com/q/437330)

Comment: Hi @mario , thanks for the answer. I try to replace cafile with capath tried to set the path to /etc/ssl/certs but email stop to work. Inside i see some symbolic links to some ca-boundle.crt - never idea on what to do. I am just understand since i add the cafile to point to my domain certificate this works for emails but not for the server so mail is working and using the right certificate, if i remove this composer will use maybe a trust server certificate that i do not know where is but not works for email. Maybe in my domain certificate i need include something else... never idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7797#issuecomment-440680491

In centos the position seems to be little bit different How to add Certificate Authority in centos7?

I found it on etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl